# Sonar fails to connect to database

Tags: sonarqube

I am using the following software:

- Sonar 3.4.1
- Mysql 5.1
- Maven 2.2.1
- Tomcat 7

I have a pom.xml file which I am trying to execute with Sonar but getting the follwing error.

```
[INFO] Building asgard-bpm
[INFO] task-segment: [sonar:sonar] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [sonar:sonar {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Sonar host: http://{host:8080}/sonar
[INFO] Sonar version: 3.4.1
[INFO] Execute: org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1:sonar
[INFO] [sonar:sonar {execution: default-sonar}]
[INFO] [14:34:54.474] Load project settings
[INFO] [14:34:54.552] Install plugins
[INFO] [14:34:56.674] Apply project exclusions
[INFO] [14:34:56.674] Install JDBC driver
[WARN] [14:34:56.736] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
[INFO] [14:34:56.736] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://host/sonar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Fail to connect to database
Connection refused: connect
```

I have created a user in the DB with the username as 'sonar' and password as 'sonarsonar'.

Created schema named 'sonar' and granted all privileges also.

BELOW IS THE PROPERTIES SET IN THE SONAR.properties file.

```
sonar.web.host:                           {127.0.0.1}
sonar.web.port:                           80
sonar.web.context:                        /


sonar.jdbc.username:                       sonar
sonar.jdbc.password:                       sonarsonar

sonar.jdbc.url:                                      {jdbc:mysql://host:3306/sonaruseUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8}
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                select 1
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this error.

Comment: Looks like your Sonar server has been configured to talke to mysql but your build is still talking to the default h2 database.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 5):

Your Sonar is not connected to your database. Check your <*.m2/settings.xml*> file. You need to change the < sonar.jdbc.url > under the properties :

```
<!-- H2 - Default DB -->
<!-- <sonar.jdbc.url>
       jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
     </sonar.jdbc.url> -->
<!-- MySQL DB -->
    <sonar.jdbc.url>
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
    </sonar.jdbc.url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure "sonar-runner.properties" to connect to MySQL Database.

Try uncommenting this lines:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```