# Sonar fails to connect to mySQL always tries jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube

This morning I have downloaded Sonar latest version. maven 3.2.5, mysql.
Sonar setup went correctly and I have the web site at 9000 working fine and all tables correctly created in mySql.
I have updated my .m2/settings.xml with the following

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <properties>
      <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true</sonar.jdbc.url>
      <sonar.jdbc.username>myuser</sonar.jdbc.username>
      <sonar.jdbc.password>mypassword</sonar.jdbc.password>
       <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

I tried **mvn sonar:sonar**, I always get

```
INFO: Work directory: /home/salam/git/spring-petclinic/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
[INFO] [00:11:25.410] Load global repositories
[INFO] [00:11:26.307] Load global repositories (done) | time=905ms
[INFO] [00:11:26.317] Server id: 20150406220059
[INFO] [00:11:26.326] User cache: /home/salam/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [00:11:26.360] Install plugins
[INFO] [00:11:26.539] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [00:11:26.554] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

I even updated **sonnar-project.properties** with

```
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
sonar.jdbc.username=myuser
sonar.jdbc.password=mypassword
```

No way, always getting the same error and sonar can not go through

I visited a couple of threads here [Sonar fails to connect to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936735/sonar-fails-to-connect-to-database)
I understand that what I have doen should make this project works fine but this is not the case

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

I solved it. I needed to add the following in the settings.xml

```
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

Comment: exact, the Maven profile must be enabled. Instead of enabling it by default, you can execute mvn sonar:sonar -Psonar